# Offline doc linking to sharepoint doc (specifically excel)?

Tags: excel-services

I searched for an answer to this and the various answers left me confused, so I figured I'd come here now since I always get a reliable answer from this forum.

I have Office365 and I use Excel Online a lot. I had an idea that would help my office save time that involves linking information saved in Excel Online to a regular Excel doc instead of having to manually put information in the regular Excel Doc (long story behind why we'd do the manual one, but it's necessary).

So I experimented and got it to work, however I noticed the sharepoint link has my username in the URL. So I had someone else try opening the standard doc and it told them it couldn't pull info from the server. Just wondering if that's a credentials thing and if there's some way around it?

Sorry, re-reading this it sounds convoluted, so I'll try for a tl;dr version:

I got my desktop Excel to load information from an Excel doc via Office365, however the desktop version only loads for me and not others. Thinking it's a credentials/login issue but not sure, trying to figure out a way around it.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the O365 file located? And do the other users have access to that location?

Comment: It's on my company's sharepoint server. The people I tested it with have access to sharepoint too, however would I need to share that document with them in Office365 for them to be able to open it? I wasn't sure if it was a file permissions thing or a server location thing or what. Here's an example of the URL:
https://mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/personal/myusername/Documents/Exceldocurl.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

The default Documents library of your My Site where the file is located is not shared. You need to grant users permission to the library in order to be able to get the data. You can move it to the Shared with Everyone folder and they should be able to access it.